# what is wrong using for_each/mem_fun

Tags: c++

I am using C++98.

I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct Foo {};

void
add_each(std::vector<std::vector<Foo*> > &vv, const Foo *f)
{
    for_each(vv.begin(), vv.end(), std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun(&std::vector<Foo*>::push_back), f));
}
```

Basically I like to add an element to the end of every vector.

G++ complains the line of for_each.

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/algorithm:62,
                 from 1.c:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h: In function â€˜_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<Foo*, std::allocator<Foo*> >*, std::vector<std::vector<Foo*, std::allocator<Foo*> >, std::allocator<std::vector<Foo*, std::allocator<Foo*> > > > >, _Funct = std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<void, std::vector<Foo*, std::allocator<Foo*> >, Foo* const&> >]â€™:
1.c:10:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:4200: error: no match for call to â€˜(std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<void, std::vector<Foo*, std::allocator<Foo*> >, Foo* const&> >) (std::vector<Foo*, std::allocator<Foo*> >&)â€™
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/backward/binders.h:146: note: candidates are: typename _Operation::result_type std::binder2nd<_Operation>::operator()(const typename _Operation::first_argument_type&) const [with _Operation = std::mem_fun1_t<void, std::vector<Foo*, std::allocator<Foo*> >, Foo* const&>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/backward/binders.h:152: note:                 typename _Operation::result_type std::binder2nd<_Operation>::operator()(typename _Operation::first_argument_type&) const [with _Operation = std::mem_fun1_t<void, std::vector<Foo*, std::allocator<Foo*> >, Foo* const&>]
```

Do you see what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for_each` will dereference the iterator and pass that result to its unary function argument. In your case, that type is `std::vector<Foo*>&`. However, [`std::mem_fun`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun) requires a *pointer* to the object it's wrapping, and not a *reference*. You should use [`std::mem_fun_ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fun_ref) instead.

```
void
add_each(std::vector<std::vector<Foo*> > &vv, const Foo *f)
{
    for_each(vv.begin(), vv.end(), 
             std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun_ref(&std::vector<Foo*>::push_back), f));
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24734cad2cff143d)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to `push_back` a `const Foo*` into a vector of `Foo*`. Either make the vector hold `const Foo*` or change the type of parameter `f` to `Foo*`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your code would be also compiled with standard libraries of the C++ 2011 then I suggest the following solution

```
void ( std::vector<Foo *>:: *pf )( Foo * const &);
pf = &std::vector<Foo *>::push_back;

std::for_each( vv.begin(), vv.end(), 
               std::bind2nd( std::mem_fun_ref( pf ), f ) );
```

The problem is that in the C++ 2011 member function `push_back` is overloaded.